# NSPredicate check for kind of object class in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a following core data model:

[image]

Now i want to fetch all Objects of type CDOnlineContact and CDOfflineContact. So i have following fetchedController:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "CDContact")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "??? %@", CDOnlineContact, CDOfflineContact) // <-- Here find only the object of class CDOnlineContact and CDOfflineContact 
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "fullname", ascending: true)]
    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: self.context.managedObjectContext!,
        sectionNameKeyPath: "firstLetter",
        cacheName: nil)
    controller.performFetch(nil)
```

I found some solutions in objective-c ...

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self isKindOfClass: %@", [NSNumber class]];
```

,but unfortunately i can't check the class in swift like this. 
Only with the query:

```
mySecretObject is CDOnlineContact
```

In NSPredicate i cannot do this. So i don't have any idea to find only object with the specified class.

Comment: Probably better way would be to create a new attribute like onlineOfflineContact on CDProfile entity, and when CDOnlineContact or CDOfflineContact save in willSave method, you could set this bool to yes which would be NO by default. That way you could fetch the contacts using simple predicate like "onlineOfflineContact = 'YES'"

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne thanks, if the classes can not be queried, then your solution is a good idea. Another solution would be if the name of the class is stored in an attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `NSPredicate` with `block` like this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate { (evaluatedObject, _) in
    return evaluatedObject is NSNumber
    // or
    // return evaluatedObject.isKindOfClass(NSNumber)
}
```

or

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF isKindOfClass:%@", argumentArray: [NSNumber.self])
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, I get following exception: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Problem with subpredicate BLOCKPREDICATE(0x7f89a1f42210)`

Comment: OK, it seems cannot use block predicates with CoreData. The `isKindOfClass` can be used Swift too.

Comment: It is thrown the same exception.

Comment: @Qeychon After trying some method, I'd suggest you save a `type` attribute as enum on your entity. It may be more easy to filter.

Comment: Yeah i also think that's the easiest solution. Thank you.